# My dropdown is not showing the data

Tags: jquery-ui

I am having a html dropdown

```
<select id="ExternalIp" onchange="externalIpchange()"></select>
```

I bind the data to dropdown through jquery and a I am passing data from controller which is working properly. I want to change the look and feel of the dropdown so I called a function

```
$("#ExternalIp").selectbox();
```

Now the look and feel of drop down is changed but it is not showing the data which I bind to dropdown. I am not getting what is the problem. Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if the jQuery plugin you are using resets the values bound to the select list.

Look for a method provided within your jQuery plugin to rebind the data which you earlier attached with jQuery or style your element first and then try binding the values.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Yes you are correct but I am not able to find that because that code is done by some one else who is not available here. If you have any idea about that type of plug in plz help.